# How to output a scalar variable as an output of a Keras model?

Tags: keras

For example, I want something like

Model(inputs=something, outputs=scalar)

This comes up where you would like to debug a model/training procedure on the case with no state "X" first (generative). So you still have a batch_size from Y. And that is what you want.

I am trying something like this:

```
V = K.variable(0, dtype=tf.float32)
V = tf.reduce_mean(x_input_not_used_by_this_branch, axis=1) * 0 + V # this is a stupid way to get things to work
model keras.models.Model(inputs=something, outputs=[V, some_other_stuff])
```

Comment: Why the negative vote? I will fix up the question as I am interested in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to use the functional API from Keras: [Keras API docu](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/)

```
inputs = Input(shape=(784,))

# a layer instance is callable on a tensor, and returns a tensor
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(inputs)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)

v = 0.25 * x

# This creates a model that includes
# the Input layer and three Dense layers
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[predictions, v])
```

Comment: This is a different model. V is a function of the inputs. I want V to be a function of nothing external. Notice the multiply by zero.